# How to edit a service definition file (SD) so as to change the Data source (User in oracle)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, map-service

- I am using Oracle 11g
- ArcGIS 10.2

  - Considering I have an enterprise geodatabase and I am connected as user1/mypass@myIP/xe
  - I create a map  from my table "mylocations"
  - I  choose share as service-->Save service definition file --> No available connection and    choose the location that my sd is stored. (in arcmap 10.2)
  - Now my SD file knows where is my DB (ip) and from which instance (user1) and table (mylocations) my data comes from.
  - I have a development team where each user has his own schema in the same xe (user1Instance, user2Instance user5Instance etc)
  - Every user should be able to work with the Same sevice but with his OWN data.
  - As a result, I suppose I have to make 5 copies of the SD file and publish it in arcgis  for sever with different service names (service1, sevice2, ...sevice5)

The question can be raised:

How could I tweak in some way the different services (I suppose by editing in some way the SD files) so as each SD to know that it will retrieve its data from now on from a different location. For example SD1 should retrieve it data from table my location BUT from User1Instance, SD2 from user2Instance ..... sd5 form user5Instance and so on.

As a result when I publish these services, having registered the respective geodatabases, the server to be able to understand where each service should fetch its data.

Comment: If you are going to be publishing 5 different services why can't they each have a separate MapDocument each looking at a different data source?  Might be easier to manage and publish.  Additionally, if you go the route of editing a definition file, you should edit the .sddraft file (xml) and not the .sd file.  See the [CreateMapSDDraft](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000006q000000) documentation for examples on editing the .sddraft and then staging it as an .sd file for publishing.

Comment: Yes but can you change the sde datasource from inside the sddraft?

Comment: I do not see a reference to any SDE datasources in the .sddraft file.  The only related resource is a reference to the publishing map document.  More of a reason to re-source at the map doc level and not during or after the publishing process.